# How subset dataframe based on last row of dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains 600 rows and More than 20K columns. Row number 600 contains number 8, 9, and 10.

I need to subset the original dataframe into:

- data8
- data9
- data10

I know this should be easier with transpose function, but later on I need to represent the images and none of the images are matching.  The issue is that I'm trying to see if not transposing the data as I retrieve it from the original file, actually helps me to solve my image presentation issue.

```
        original_df <- as.data.frame(file)
        data8 <- original_df [(original_df [785,] == 8),]
```

Data frame contains again, 0 and 1's for the image. The last row contains numbers 8, 9, 10. I want to filter to data8 to contain all columns with row 600th being number 8.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I don't understand your concern about transposing.) The j-position (column selection) for arguments to "[" can be logical. (And it appears you are already thinking of something similar except your choice of the 785th row doesn't fit the problem description.

```
data8 <- data[ , data[600, ] == 8 ]
data9<- data[ , data[600, ] == 9 ]
data10<- data[ , data[600, ] == 10 ]
```

Comment: I know I'm just receiving feedback that I shouldn't be transposing the original dataframe...I agree with you I don't know, but thank you so much for the feedback and the help.

Comment: Using the "[" function wouldn't transpose. It's using `apply` or `sapply` that might transpose.